# Django Views - How does it work?

Tags: python, django

I'm a little bit confused on how Django's views work. I thought it worked this way:

1. User  pressed a button on a html page
2. The action is linked to a view, so it goes to the function as defined in the url.py, and then it does some logic.

However below I have an index.html page that will redirect the user to a login page if the user is NOT logged in:

```
def index(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/login.html')
    else:
        result = Hello_World.delay()
        somethingDownByCelery = result.get(timeout=2)
        context = {'somethingDownByCelery': somethingDownByCelery, 'userName': request.user.username}
        return render(request, 'webapp/index.html', context)
```

Then I have a login.html, I have a logger that records users behaviors on each of the webpage.

```
def loginUser(request):
    logger = logging.getLogger('views.logger.login')
    try:
        username = request.POST['username'];
        logger.info("User:" + username + " in Login Page");
    except:
        logger.error("Cannot Identify User");

    type = ""

    try:
        type = request.POST['submit']
        logger.info("User:" + username + " requests:" + type);
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        logger.error("Cannot Identify User's Request");

    try:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('index.html')
            else:
                return redirect('disabled.html')
        else:
            condition = "Invalid Login"
            context = {'condition': condition}
            return render(request, 'webapp/login.html', context)
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        context = None
        return render(request, 'webapp/login.html', context)
```

The problem is that when the webpage is refreshed, or redirected to, it will get two logger.error in the two exceptions when I'm trying to request POST with username and submit, because I thought the behavior was 1(press the button in the webpage) then 2(run the function in views).

However, somehow it goes through the whole function first then generate a webpage, which is a 3 step procedure?

Comment: "getting logger.error"? What does that even mean? You _do_ have more than one `error()` call in this snippet, y'know...

Comment: Sorry, added a clarification. It gives me two errors, which are "Cannot Identify User" and "Cannot Identify User's Request".

Comment: ...so you're hitting both except: clauses. That shouldn't be a surprise, since this redirect isn't POSTing to /login.

Comment: I'm still confused, why would a redirect or a refresh on the page run through the whole function?

Comment: A redirect loads the page. What would you expect a page load to do *other than* invoke the view handler in full?

Comment: To be clear: The page isn't even sent to the user in the first place until after the function has been completely run end-to-end. Thus, the user never even sees the button (because the page the button is on has not yet been sent to them) until the function has already run.

Comment: ...because until you get to `return render('webapp/login.html')`, nothing knows that `login.html` is what the user's browser is supposed to get, and that return is all the way down at the end of the function.

Comment: Ah, I get it now, I thought the page will load up first then somehow wait for the user. Thanks for the help, I'm very new to Django :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Django executes a redirect, it executes the code for that view first, before rendering the actual page. Your code is executing loginUser(), and is triggering exceptions in both the first and second try blocks, which causes your logger statements.

So assuming you're coming from index and are not authenticated, the process goes something like:

- index()

  - redirect('/login.html') [this will call whatever view is mapped to that url; you may want to consider using the url resolution django offers]
- loginUser()

  - return render(request, 'webapp/login.html', context)
- create and return the html to the user